# x11grab from another display server

Tags: xorg, ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg with x11grab on my local machine, but I want to capture the screen of an X server on 12.34.56.78. How can I do that? The following doesn't work:

```
 ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 800x600 -i 12.34.56.78:0.0 screen.avi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote X server must give you permission to contact him. The simplest solution were:

```
xhost +
```

..given on the remote side. But warn, it enabled this grab thing for everybody & everywhere, which you probably won't. In this case a better solution were a

```
xhost +1.2.3.4
```

...where 1.2.3.4 is the ip from which you the remote X server contact.

If you want to be very secure, you could use `xauth` as well, [here](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=Howto&pagename=Remote-X-Apps/Remote-X-Apps-6.html) you can find a tutorial to that (it is 2-3 commands or so).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I was connecting to a Windows machine running XMing, and you can achieve this by going through the XLaunch program and checking the "disable access control" checkbox.